# Is there a standard function in javascript to convert a string to something argv like

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a chatbot that lets the user input commands like:

> .command -a "something with spaces" -b

and on the JavaScript side, I want to convert the command into an argument array like

> ['a', 'something with spaces', 'b']

While I know I can make my own parser for this, I was wondering if there anything standard I could use to parse this string into this. (I don't know if I'm using the right vocabulary here as I'm copying the format and not sure how to properly refer to everything)

Comment: no there is not

Comment: use regex to get the value

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
let str = '.command -a "something with spaces" -b'
let regex = /^(.command)([ ])(-[a-z]+)([ ])(.*)([ ])(-[a-z]+)$/
let res = str.match(regex)
console.log([res[3], res[5], res[7]])
```

Comment: While this does work, this doesn't answer the question, but thx so much for answering. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: ok can you please eloborate your requirement. so can give a solution

Comment: The question was whether or not there was a standard way to do this, and as Jaromanda X simply said, there isn't. That is really all that was needed for the answer. A more complete answer would probably explain what was the format I was copying (after some research, I think it is Shellwords).